# Automatically sending files to your Dropbox Account via email

Tags: email, dropbox

Is it possible to, say, email files via attachment to your Dropbox account? As opposed to manually placing the file on the Dropbox folder on your computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present (February 2011) this isn't possible to do using Dropbox.  It is on the [wish list though](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/20/email-files-to-dropbox).

An alternative service is available called [SendToDropBox](http://sendtodropbox.com/) if you are happy to use a third party.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a third-party service, you can use [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com). There are a number of ways to do that, either by sending email to IFTTT's mailbox (`trigger@applet.ifttt.com`) or to your own as a trigger, and then uploading the file to your Dropbox.

I used the [email channel](https://ifttt.com/email) to set a trigger where if I send an email message from my registered address to IFTTT's mailbox with `#dropbox` in the subject, that'll use the [Dropbox](https://ifttt.com/dropbox) "add file from URL" action to save a file to the `IFTTT/email` directory in my Dropbox and the *rest* of the subject as the filename.

(Here's [a public recipe](https://ifttt.com/applets/39p-when-you-receive-an-email-attachment-automatically-save-it-to-dropbox) that essentially does the same thing.)